# Cleanest way to suppress FXML version warnings without changing java version

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

## Summary

We are developing FXML with Scene Builder 10 and loading it on an app with JRE 8. We are confident that our FXML is all Java 8 compliant, but would like to suppress the following warnings that are printed whenever an FXML file is loaded:

```
Dec 19, 2018 12:50:14 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.192
```

We've thought of a variety of solutions, but none of them seem very good. I just want to know if anyone can think of anything better.

Note that there are a few questions on SO that seem very similar to this, but so far it seems like they were all resolved by just updating to a newer JRE, which is not an option for us.

## Background

Our apps get shipped to a variety of customers, some of whom are unwilling to update past JRE 8. It turns out that Scene Builder for java 10 is WAY faster than Scene Builder for Java 8 (not sure why). As a result, we'd like to keep using Scene Builder for Java 10, but we always write our code to be Java 8 compliant and we always do all of our testing with JRE 8.

## Workarounds

There are a variety of workarounds we've thought of, but they all seem a little hacky and definitely more like workarounds than true solutions. What I would really like to see would be either a way to tell Scene Builder to use an older API version, or to tell the FXML loader to ignore the version number. It's looking like that's probably not possible though.

### Manually change the version number in FXML

It's not hard to just change the `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1"` attribute to `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.192"` but it gets updated every time you modify it in Scene Builder and it's a pain to have to keep changing it. I thought about making a git hook to do it automatically on commit, but we're using Eclipse and the egit hook integration is practically non-existent.

### Redirect Stderr on FXML load

We could make an FXMLLoading utility that we use for all FXML loading. It would could essentially disable stderr prior to loading it and then reenable it. This would not be thread safe though and anything else that might be printed to stderr at the same time would be lost.

We could also redirect stderr to an object that determines what should be printed based on the currently running thread, or perhaps by just omitting text that matches the FXML warning we're seeing. This still seems sort of hacky though.

### Use custom input stream to load FXML

We could create an FXML loading utility that uses [`load(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) and pass it in a custom `InputStream` that filters out or modifies that `xmlns` attribute. I think that this is probably my favorite solution, but it still seems like sort of a hassle.

Comment: FXMLs are xml files. It should be pretty simple to write a program replacing the attribute value. If you run this program during your deploy process, you should get rid of the warnings without having to rewrite the files manually. Just be sure to actually do tests with the JavaFX version you replace the attribute value with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem developing with SceneBuilder 21 for JRE 17.
There is a simple solution to this annoyance.
Add the following line to SceneBuilder.cfg:

```
java-options=-Djavafx.version=
```

to get this in *.fxml:

```
<... xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

or for JRE17 in SceneBuilder.cfg:

```
java-options=-Djavafx.version=17
```

to get this in *.fxml:

```
<... xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

SceneBuilder.cfg in Windows/Linux is found where the SceneBuilder-VV-V.jar is installed, in macOS you have to go inside SceneBuilder.app ->

`/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/app/SceneBuilder.cfg`

Note: So far there are no negative effects having no version number at all in the fxml file (The fact that the compatibility check is done by the used JAVA-IDE is IMHO safeguard enough)